# Why do I need to extend an Activity in Android?

Tags: android

This is a question about fundamentals: why do I need to declare a class `public class MainActivity extends Activity`?

Comment: because the android architect and UI instance is there like `AppCompatActivity` , `Activity` , `Fragment` etc

Answer (score 5):

Activity is the base class to build the screens of your application and it has all the lifecycle callbacks expected by the Android Framework.

Answer (score 3):

As the Android application launches `Activity` instances, you need to implement your own activity. In Java, it is done by extending the original `Activity` class. The `public class` prefix is to indicate that this is a class and that it can be launched by classes from other packages and places (as the Dalvik VM)

Answer (score 3):

In android, the user interface of an application is displayed on a device through an Activity, typically with one Activity created for each unique screen. Internally there is a stack of Activities, when moving from one screen to another, the next Activity to be visible is pushed onto the top of the stack – put another way, the Activity on the top of the stack is what is visible on the display. Activities are popped from the stack by pressing the back button, which resumes the previous Activity.

**When you want to create a new Activity, you extend the Activity class.** 
The code below shows a simple starting point:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every android screen contain the one java file(activity) and one xml file(layout).
activity life cycle contain the 4 stages and 7 methods.those are all present in the android.app.activity class .so in order to achieve those properties to your newly created class by extending the activity class.

Answer (score -1):

Because when you want to open another layout/design you need to extend the Activity.That's why you need to extend the activity to see the another activity. ;).